# Is accessing projects through Roboflow API restricted to the paid plans?

Tags: roboflow

Is the project access through API only limited to paid plans. I am using a Private sandbox and when I try to access the project using the roboflow API its giving me errors.

```
import roboflow

rf = roboflow.Roboflow("MY-API-KEY")
project = rf.workspace().project('MY-PROJECT-NAME)
```

```
RuntimeError: {
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Dataset with ID `xxxx` does not exist or cannot be loaded due to missing permissions.",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "hint": "You can find the API docs at https://docs.roboflow.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API and pip library are available for free accounts as well.

My guess would be that the project ID isn’t quite right; this should be the unique identifier.

Does rf.workspace().projects() give you a list of your projects?

Comment: Thanks Brad, I can access the projects list by using the above command. How about the models and the dataset for the projects -- access through api for models and dataset is limited to paid users right ?

Comment: No, there are currently no parts of the API that are restricted to paid users. It sounds like you're probably not using the correct project identifier which is what's producing that error. The `id` property on the Project that comes back via the project list is what you want to use. It should be all lower case with no whitespace eg `my-project-xyz`.